# Parse INI in Perl (list format)

Tags: perl, parsing, ini

What is the best way to parse ini files in Perl?

the file is formated in this way:

```
[group1]
value1
value2
value3

[group2]
value1
value2
value3
value4

[group3]
value1
value2
```

Comment: Looks like there's options on CPAN for reading them. [Config::INI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI) etc.

Comment: Config::IniFiles

Comment: I have looked but the format is different. most expect a "param=value" format

Comment: If it doesn't have a `param=value` format, then [it's not an INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), and your question is "How do I parse something that is sort of but not quite like an INI file?"

Comment: Yes its actually .conf but formatted similar to INI. any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any errors? How is the actual output different from the expected output? What isn't working with your existing solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us the expected format for the data or shown any existing code, so it's impossible to know what you're looking for, but this should get you at least 90% of the way there:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %config;
my $group = '';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /\S/;

    if (/^\[([^]]+)\]/) {
        $group = $1;
        next;
    }

    push(@{$config{$group}}, $_);
}

print Dumper(\%config);

__DATA__
[group1]
value1
value2
value3

[group2]
value1
value2
value3
value4

[group3]
value1
value2
```

Comment: he should use one of the available packages in CPAN rather than roll his own

Comment: @EdwardKirton Which module do you suggest?

Comment: Config::Simple is easy to use.

Comment: @EdwardKirton And does Config::Simple work with the format of the file in the question? Nope.

Comment: The example text given isn't proper INI format, which was specified the question, probably just a mistake in the OP.  My point is, it's best to use a standardized file format and there are many robust packages available to use.