# Edit/Match a string n lines below some specific match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Hi recently I've posted a problem.
[edit nth line below a line match in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587929/edit-match-a-string-n-lines-below-some-specific-match-in-bash/58589173?noredirect=1#comment103491842_58589173)
(Problem: I have to edit the `PROTOCOL` line 3 lines below `[MARATHON]`)

This is the file:

```
# /etc/ndxconfig.ini will override this file
# if APP_ID is added in service propery, service discovery will be using marathon;
# HOST/PORT specified will override values retrieved from marathon

[MARATHON]
HOSTS = {{ ','.join(groups['marathon'])}}
PORT = 8080
PROTOCOL = http
SECRET = SGpQIcjK2P7RYnrdimhhhGg7i8MdmUqwvA2JlzbyujFS4mR8M88svI7RfNWt5rnKy4WHnAihEZmmIUb940bnlYmnu47HdUHE


[MYSQL]
; APP_ID = /neon/infra/mysql
HOST = {{keepalived_mysql_virtual_ip}}
PORT = 3306
SECRET = tIUFN1rjjDBdEXUsOJjPEtdieg8KhwTzierD48JsgDeYc84DD6Uy5a6kzHfKolq1MNS1DKwlSqxENk33UulJd9DPHPzYCxFm
```

The problem is if I rerun the script in some case, the
`sed '/\[MARATHON\]/{N;N;N;s/http/https/;}' <file>` will append more and more `s` to `http` (`httpsssss`).
So I would add a positive lookahead in regex for `s`. 
I can do it with **perl -pe** but do not know how I **do it on nth line below a match**.
Please Help. How can I do it?

Comment: it is nice to refer to another Q&A, but add all details related to current question in this post itself.. for ex: it is not clear why you need to run the script multiple times.. in any case, your given example might work with `s/http$/https/` so that `http` is changed only if it is at the end of line

Comment: You may use word boundaries in GNU `sed`: `sed '/\[MARATHON\]/{N;N;N;s/\<http\>/https/;}' `

Comment: Added a non-perl answer to your first question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a GNU sed, the solution can be using word boundaries:

```
sed '/\[MARATHON\]/{N;N;N;s/\<http\>/https/;}' file 
#                          ^^     ^^
```

You may also leverage context details. As the `http` is after `PROTOCOL` you may simply use this to reset the value:

```
sed '/\[MARATHON\]/{N;N;N;s/\(.*= *\).*/\1https/;}' file
```

The `\(.*= *\).*` will match and capture the key with `=` and optional spaces and its value is restored with `\1` while `https` will always re-write the value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner, which does exactly what you asked for: *edit a string n lines below some specific match in Perl*. But also consider **NOTES** below.

```
cat file | perl -lpe '
$seen = 1 if m{\[MARATHON\]}xms;
$num_lines++ if $seen;
s{ \A ( PROTOCOL \s+ = \s+ ) http }{${1}https}xms if $num_lines == 4;
'
```

**NOTES:**

The code above answers the question, but it is poor code. Why? It is generally a bad idea to parse a known, widely used format relying *only* on the expected patterns and the expected number of lines. Here, the format seems to be `.ini`, so consider searching for modules/libraries used for parsing/reading/writing `config ini` files. For example:

- Config::IniFiles - A module for reading .ini-style configuration files: https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles
- Config::INI - simple .ini-file format: https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI

If you do not want to use the modules such as the ones above, at least consider the possible future changes to the input and using fewer assumptions in your code. In this case, the assumption of the *n*th line from the section header seems the **least** robust to change. The `ini` parsers in the upstream code that write this file may not care about the order of the lines. The section headers are more robust. Perhaps read the entire file (`slurp`) and change to `https` using a non-greedy multi-line regex from `[MARATHON]` to `PROTOCOL = http`. Do not specify the exact number of lines, just make sure the line you change is in the same section. **But this is still reinventing the wheel - avoid doing it if you can.**

**SEE ALSO:**

- [Parse INI in Perl (list format)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52432889)
- [How can I access INI files from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2014862)